# Website slow response slow from some locations

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

Website slow response slow  from some locations

I have a web server hosted in AWS Oregon region.

Our customer are accessing this website from a different part of the world (mostly from US, UK, and Dubai)
static assets are already on the AWS CloudFront
Now a day most of the customer from Dubai and UK are complaining that our web site is very slow but in the same time, we tried to access the website from the USA and other location but its fast.
what cloud be the best solution to make the site fast for all the customer in different locations.

web server is under ELB and we are using the SSL (ACM) certificate on the ELB for https.

Please suggest me the best solution. what about the Route53 latency bases routing .. will this work for my case.

Comment: If your CloudFront has already cached your content and your users are still experiencing high latency then there is a problem with how you are using the cache. Start by monitoring cache hit/miss ratio. I would guess that you have a lot of cache misses caused by either low TTL value, or dynamic nature of your content. Another possibility is that you are using dynamic URLs. Each such URL would be treated as something that has not yet been placed into the cache event if the actual content that is requests already resides in the cache.

Answer (score 0):

In AWS you have a lot of regions. Many of them closer to your costumers. So, why not replicate the server to a closer region to match your costumers location. It's a looong way from Oregon to UK and Dubai.

EDIT:

shahid: "so your saying we have to setup to on web server on every region.whihc will cost us a lot more."

@shahid it's not in all aws regions, maybe just one it's enough for your problem. For your example (uk and dubai) , you can set an instance in France or London that are a lot closer than Oregon. This is what it's cloud. And this is why cloud was created. Since you already have the assets in cloud front you have to do the same with servers, and the way to do that is to clone the instance to the closest region. Without this solution you are going back to the old times (one server for all the world) = no cloud = large traveling times

EDIT2:
you can try use some tool like pingdom to check the differences response times across the world. With this you can check and verify that the connection is a lot faster from Oregon that was from UK and Dubai. You will also see the response times from cloudfront, to check that it's working as it should